# Drupal : curl call + view file pdf

Tags: php, drupal-7

I would like to make a curl call to another server to retrieve a pdf file
Then I want to view this file on my Drupal website.
But there is one problem: We can not change the header in the Drupal Module !

```
$CurlConnect = curl_init();
        $fields = array(
                                'param1' => $p1,
                                'param2' => $p2,
                        );

    $fields_string = '';
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
        rtrim($fields_string, '&');
        curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://test....');
        curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_POST,   1);
        curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        $Result = curl_exec($CurlConnect);

        header('Cache-Control: public'); 
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');

        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="fichier.pdf"');

        header('Content-Length: '.strlen($Result));

        echo $Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if would it work but hope it helps

Maybe call a function from a hook menu item

Instead of usgin curl you can use [drupal_http_request](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) (This function do not uses curl)

And before returning the pdf, change the heeaders with [drupal_add_http_header](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_add_http_header/7)